# Quick way to create JSF custom component

Tags: jsf, components, facelets

I know of two ways of creating custom JSF components:
1. Native JSF way: creating JSF component class, tag, etc.
2. Facelets way: defining component in a xhtml file and then creating appropriate decrption in facelets taglib.

Currently I work on a project in which introducing facelets is unfortunately out of the question. On the other hand, creating custom components the standard JSF way seems like a pain in the ass.

Is there maybe a third party library that allows creating custom components in the way similar to facelets but doesn't entail the need of using non-standard renderer?

Comment: @Boz: Don't think since "facelets is out of question" and creating components with JSF 2.0 and Facelets is actually a piece of cake. A pain in the ass sounds like JSF 1.x since it's pretty verbose/opaque ;)

Comment: 1.0/1.1 or 1.2? Creating components is a bit different in 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a limited amount of templating using (for example) [jsp:include](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref209.html#1003408) and [f:subview](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/f/subview.html).

Alternatively, you can extend a [UIComponent](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/package-frame.html) overriding selected methods and then provide it via an existing tag and a managed bean using the `binding` attribute. This still requires a reasonably detailed understanding of component development (and the consequences of this choice), but could cut down the number of files/volume of code significantly.

This approach is a bit of a hack, but might be OK for short-term stuff. You wouldn't do it for component libraries you want to distribute or components requiring long term maintenance.

The new component:

```
public class QuickComponent extends HtmlOutputText {
  @Override public void encodeAll(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.writeText("I'm not really a HtmlOutputText", null);
    for (UIComponent kid : getChildren()) {
      if (kid instanceof UIParameter) {
        UIParameter param = (UIParameter) kid;
        writer.startElement("br", this);
        writer.endElement("br");
        writer.writeText(param.getName() + "=" + param.getValue(), null);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The bean providing an instance:

```
/**Request-scope managed bean defined in faces-config.xml*/
public class QuickComponentProviderBean {
  private QuickComponent quick;

  public void setQuick(QuickComponent quick) {
    this.quick = quick;
  }

  public QuickComponent getQuick() {
    if (quick == null) {
      quick = new QuickComponent();
    }
    return quick;
  }
}
```

*Note: don't reuse a single bean property for multiple tags in your views, or they'll reference the same object instance.*

Adding the new component to the view:

```
<h:outputText binding="#{quickComponentProviderBean.quick}">
  <f:param name="Hello" value="World" />
</h:outputText>
```

*Note: the attributes that can be defined have not changed. They're fixed by the TLD.*